# User folder on Windows EMPTY

Tags: windows, files, playonlinux

After I installed PlayOnLinux, I wanted to install a Windows program that is located in my Windows User folder that is on different partition. But it was 'empty' before I knew it! I don't know if it's really gone or just hidden. I've tried Show Hidden Files and writing the location manually but still failed.

Please let me know what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows folder on PlayOnLinux and Wine do not store your Windows files and/or programs. The Windows folder is used to create a space where all the files needed to run a windows program is located, excluding Windows boot mechanisms and YOUR Windows. It's not the Windows located on your hard disk, it's just a dummy folder and will not hold any of your data at all.

The thing you need to do instead of this is to copy the installed files from Windows to a thumb drive, external drive, CD or whatever or load the disc of the game, or get the installation package from wherever and [follow the instructions here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/manual.html).

I highly recommend Wine as an alternative, because PlayOnLinux is actually based off Wine and personally I find Wine so much easier to use and there are many more [support pages and documentations to read and discover](http://www.winehq.org/).

The only advice I can offer to you now is **read the documentation**! That should've told you everything I just wrote, and use YouTube and Google - because they are great sources.

Comment: What I meant was the user folder of Windows. Anyways, I've deleted Windows as the folder seems to be impossible to be recovered.

Comment: @hudadiaz, OH! Gosh, forgive me! I'm not too sure about this, you do indeed have an unusual situation. You've probably tried Ctrl+H to show hidden files/folders, but since you've said that your folder is now non-existent, I'm not too sure if it is in fact salvageable.